# Linux : governer set to userspace in kernel but is always set to ondemand after the system's booted

Tags: linux, power-management

I am using the 3.2 Linux kernel on a custom ARM board with Debian Wheezy.  My kernel config. for power management is below.  I want the system to default to the userspace governer (which the kernel config. seems to specify), but after I'm booted it's always set to ondemand.  How can I change this so the system boots to userspace?

```
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_TABLE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_STAT=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_STAT_DETAILS=y
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_PERFORMANCE is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_POWERSAVE is not set
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_USERSPACE=y
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_ONDEMAND is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_CONSERVATIVE is not set
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_PERFORMANCE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_POWERSAVE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_USERSPACE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_ONDEMAND=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_CONSERVATIVE=y
```

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1369817

Comment: @PiotrWadas how is that relevant to Linux? Those are the governors for android.

Comment: The link above was useful so I could potentially see new types of governer out there.  My problem remains however, according to my kernel config the governer is set to userspace, but by the time the system has booted it's in ondemand mode.  OS is Debian 7 ARMHF.

Comment: I admit I'm not an expert on the subj., but what difference does it make in what state system boots up? I mean, what's the diff. between system booting in some other state or enforcing type of governor after bootup in some init script, wherever? Does eg. booting on your board eats so much battery, that you're hoping in particular state will let you save some?You could play with modules avoiding their loading at boot, to make some mode unavailable at bootup and available later, by some custom trick, you could even dive into kernel source and find out,anyway I think problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I was interested in why after booting it's using the on-demand governer, but the kernel is set to userspace.  I would like it to boot up to the userspace governer.